# Adding reference to .net assembly which has dots in name and namespace

Tags: python, .net, .net-assembly, python.net

I am trying to refer to assembly which has dots in the namespace.

```python
sys.path.append(assemblyPath)

clr.FindAssembly(r"isc.Eng.Hov")
clr.AddReference(r"isc.Eng.Hov")

print 'isc.Eng.Hov' in clr.ListAssemblies(False)

from isc.Eng.Hov import *
```

Interpreter raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
True
  File "/mnt/86f8c6c8-9099-4f32-be68-486a12918546/GoogleDrive/__BACKLOG/RMK_API_LIB/rmkSuppliersDLLswrappers/scr/Hoval/__phex_hoval_dllwrapper.py", line 14, in <module>
    from isc.Eng.Hov import *
ImportError: No module named isc.Eng.Hov
```

How to troubleshoot?

Comment: I was also trying `imp.find_module('isc.Eng.Hov')` with no success

Comment: isc.Eng.Hov is your namespace in assembly? Use clr.AddReference(assembly_name_with_path_without_ext).

Comment: If I refer to only dll_name_with_no_ext, then:
`clr.AddReference(r"isc.Eng.Hov")`
`print 'isc.Eng.Hov' in clr.ListAssemblies(False)`
I have True as output. So the reference was added

Comment: Oh, sorry the path to DLL is not needed - I was still waking up ;)

Comment: OK:) no problem

Comment: The output of both FindAssembly and AddReference will tell you if it is found. Right now you are silencing this output.

Comment: I am sorry @denfromufa I can't understand you

Comment: It said True @denfromufa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125710/discussion-between-denfromufa-and-artem-zhukov).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution was to use [ILSPY](http://ilspy.net/) to investigate the DLL and find dependencies (right click recursively for each DLL and click on add dependencies). Then I copied all the dependencies to the same folder where the main DLL was. After that, I ran:

```python
print [a for a in clr.ListAssemblies(False)
```

and get the list of dependencies which are actually involved:

```python
u'isc.Eng.Hov', u'Microsoft.VisualBasic', u'System.Windows.Forms', u'System.Drawing', u'Accessibility'
```

and left them in the folder.
After doing so the part of code:

```python
sys.path.append(assemblyPath)

clr.AddReference("isc.Eng.Hov")

import isc.Eng.Hov as isk
from isk import *
```

started work.

Thank you all, especially @denfromufa for help!

Comment: So, it's that the assembly failed to load but there was no indication of this in `AddReference`? Not the best UX I'd say and might warrant a bug report or something.

Comment: Sorry @ivan_pozdeev I didn't get you

Comment: You say that the root cause was that the assembly couldn't load due to missing dependencies. But you didn't get any exception or just about anything to indicate this. So, Python.NET could see some improvement here.

Comment: Still happening to me in 2022.